# How can a vector be orthogonal to a plane, but parallel to a vector used to describe that plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

I see in my textbook the following:

- $S_1$ is a plane defined by $a_1$ and $a_2$
- $S_2= \{ z+y_1a_1+y_2a_2| a_1^Tz=a_2^Tz=0, -1 \le y_1 \le 1\}$, $S_2$ is a slab parallel to $a_2$ and orthogonal to $S_1$

It was my understanding that for a vector to be orthogonal to a plane, it should be orthogonal to every vector in that plane.  So, I do not understand how it is possible here to have a slab that is parallel to one of the vectors used to construct the plane, but it is orthogonal to the plane itself?

In other words, how is it possible for $S_2$ to be parallel to $a_2$, and also orthogonal to $S_1$?

Comment: Note that two orthogonal planes define a common line (vector) which lies in each of them.

Comment: So you are telling me that $S_2$ is just an intersection between $S_1$ and a plane that is orthogonal to $S_1$.  That means that $S_2=a_2$, true?

Comment: A slab is not a vector, it is more like a thickened plane. Two planes are said to be orthogonal if their normal vectors are orthogonal. What is the center-plane of $S_2$ (obtained by setting $y_1=0$), and what is its normal?

Comment: The vector used to describe the plane is typically orthogonal to it.

Comment: So....the only way this makes sense to me is if $a_2 \in S_2$, and the line corresponding to where $S_1$ intersects with $S_2$ is $a_2$.   This ensures that $a_2 \in S_1$ and $S_2 \perp S_1$ (that is, the orthogonal complement of $S_1$ is $S_2$, and the intersection between two planes is a line).

Comment: @Rahul do you mind posting an answer?  I am interested in your opinion.